# python - A problem happen when I'm trying to fetch documents from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to download documents from this page
[Securities Class Action Filings](http://securities.stanford.edu/fmi/xsl/SCACPUDB/recordlist.xsl?-db=SCACPUDB&-lay=Search&FIC_DateFiled_Quater=Q1&FIC_DateFiled_Year=2011&-sortfield.1=FIC_DateFiled&-sortfield.2=LitigationName&-sortorder.1=ascend&-max=25&-find)

I tried to download the 25 documents on the page.
I thought it was simple, and here's my code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
  pre_url = "http://securities.stanford.edu"
  url = "http://securities.stanford.edu/fmi/xsl/SCACPUDB/recordlist.xsl?-db=SCACPUDB&-lay=Search&FIC_DateFiled_Quater=Q1&FIC_DateFiled_Year=2011&-sortfield.1=FIC_DateFiled&-sortfield.2=LitigationName&-sortorder.1=ascend&-max=25&-find" 
  response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read()).findAll('tr')
  url_list = []
  for s in soup[8:]:
    url_list.append(pre_url + s.a['href'])
  for x in url_list:
    name = x.split("/")[4]  
    context = urllib2.urlopen(x).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(context)
    file = open(name + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(soup.prettify())
  print "DONE"
```

After executing the script, I downloaded 25 files successfully.
But then I found 10 of them are full of garbage characters!
How come?
Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot, and I'm sorry for my poor English.

Update:
This is one of the pages which would be downloaded incorrectly by the script
http://securities.stanford.edu/1046/BWEN00_01/

Comment: "garbage characters" is misleading.  Provide actual examples.  If you use the wrong tool, you're file full of Unicode will not appear to be "garbage" when it's really just UTF-16 Unicode.

Comment: garbage characters are something like this:䠼䵔㹌䠼䅅㹄吼呉䕌䴾湡歮湩⁤潃灲牯瑡潩⁮ⴠ匠捥牵瑩敩⁳汃獡⁳†捁楴湯⼼䥔䱔㹅ഠ㰍䕍䅔丠䵁㵅䐧卅剃偉䥔乏‧佃呎久㵔㰧㹢畓浭牡㩹⼼㹢䄠捣牯楤杮琠⁯⁡牰獥⁳敲敬獡⁥慤整⁤敆牢慵祲㈠‬〲ㄱ‬慍湮楋摮椠⁳⁡楢灯慨浲捡略楴慣⁬潣灭湡⁹潦畣敳⁤湯琠敨搠獩潣敶祲‬敤敶潬浰湥⁴湡⁤潣浭牥楣污穩瑡潩⁮景琠敨慲数瑵捩瀠潲畤瑣⁳潦⁲楤敳獡獥‬畳档愠⁳楤扡

Comment: That doesn't help much - you need to *update* the question with the ``repr()`` of the "garbage" characters.  You also need to include the headers that come with the page, since the headers provide language and -- most importantly -- encoding information.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a page that you can download correctly by yourself (with the browser) but which is downloaded incorrectly by your program?

Comment: http://securities.stanford.edu/1046/BWEN00_01/

Comment: Please **update** the question when you own it.  Please do not add comments to your own question.  Please make the question complete and consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample page is encoded in UTF-16 without properly providing that factoid in the header.

```
>>> page = urllib2.urlopen( "http://securities.stanford.edu/1046/BWEN00_01" )
>>> page.info().headers
['Date: Mon, 22 Aug 2011 13:13:56 GMT\r\n', 'Server: Apache/1.3.33 (Darwin) mod_jk/1.2.2 DAV/1.0.3\r\n', 'Cache-Control: max-age=60\r\n', 'Expires: Mon, 22 Aug 2011 13:14:56 GMT\r\n', 'Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Jul 2011 22:06:51 GMT\r\n', 'ETag: "18b9a6e-9af6-4e28a2fb"\r\n', 'Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n', 'Content-Length: 39670\r\n', 'Connection: close\r\n', 'Content-Type: text/html\r\n']
```

Try `page.decode('utf-16')` to see the page in proper Unicode characters instead of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(name + ".txt", "w")
```

It's possible that your problem is that you're opening the files in text mode, but they're being downloaded in binary mode. Replace the above expression with

```
open(name + ".txt", "wb")
```

and see if it improves things.